# Nodejs: Error starting web application in production environment

Tags: node.js, babeljs, package.json

When I try to start my web application with Nodejs only, I've no any problem and my web application works fine.

But when I try to simulate in my laptop the start in production, namely, the static pages will be served by webpack server and the data from the API will be served by Nodejs. I've got this error:

```
/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:61
  return SafeBuffer.Buffer.from(json, 'utf8').toString('base64');
                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'from' of undefined
    at Converter.toBase64 (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:61:28)
    at Converter.toComment (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/convert-source-map/index.js:65:21)
    at generateCode (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/generate.js:78:76)
    at runSync (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/index.js:50:51)
    at transformSync (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:43:38)
    at Object.transform (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transform.js:22:38)
    at compile (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js:73:20)
    at compileHook (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/node.js:102:12)
    at Module._compile (/home/josecarlos/Workspace/nodejs/basketmetrics3/node_modules/pirates/lib/index.js:93:29)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:827:10)
```

To start my project I use this command *npm run start*

These are my config files:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "basketmetrics3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Basketball advanced stats",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client",
    "compile-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",    
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run compile && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.4",
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "create-react-app": "^3.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "d3": "^5.9.7",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-graphql": "^0.7.1",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^1.6.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.15.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^3.1.7",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.0.7",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-multi-language": "^0.4.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-simple-tooltip": "^2.6.1",
    "sequelize": "^4.44.2",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.5.5",        
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.38.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env" , {"modules": "cjs"}], 
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties"
    ],
    "ignore": [
        "./node_modules"
    ]
}
```

I have been looking for information about my problem and I have found that I have to add "ignore: [node_modules]" to my .babelrc file. But, after I have added this entry in my .babelrc file, my application still doesn't work :(

Is there any other way to ignore "node_modules" with node.js? How can I ignore "node_modules"? If this is the real reason of my error, of course.

What can I do to fix the error that I've got?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to my problem. Changing the start script adding the ignore of "node_modules" is enough.

My "start" script in package.json will be:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev-webpack": "webpack-dev-server --hot --mode development",
    "clean": "rm -rf ./dist",
    "dev": "npm run clean && npm run compile-dev && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./src/client",
    "compile-dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -d --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "compile": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --config ./webpack.config.babel.js --progress",
    "start": "npm run clean && npm run compile && cross-env NODE_ENV=production babel-node src/server/server.js --ignore ./node_modules"
  },
```